# Gradle Javadoc custom task

Tags: gradle, javadoc

I'm facing a problem when trying to launch a custom Javadoc task in Gradle.
In my old Ant script, I was using

```
<javadoc access="private">
  <doclet name="com.xxx.CustomDoclet" path="customDoclet.jar" />
  <classpath refid="execute.path" />
  <packageset dir="${src}" defaultexcludes="yes" excludes="inprogress/**" />
  <fileset dir="${target}/tmp" defaultexcludes="yes" includes="**/*Test.java" />
</javadoc>
```

The customDoclet.jar was a home-made doclet used to generate some informations (it was not really a javadoc per se). But it worked perfectly.

I imported in Gradle like the following :

```
task extractRequirements(type: Javadoc) {
  source = zipTree(zipFile).matching{ filter ->
    filter.include '**/*Test.java'
    filter.exclude 'inprogress/**'
  }
  destinationDir = file("$buildDir/requirements")
  options.docletpath = configurations.jaxDoclet.files.asType(List)
  options.doclet = 'com.xxx.CustomDoclet'
}

configurations {
  jaxDoclet
}

dependencies {
  jaxDoclet 'com:customdoclet:1.0'
}
```

Gradle tells me :
:extractRequirements
Executing task ':extractRequirements' (up-to-date check took 0.109 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
Starting process 'command '/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/javadoc''. Working directory: /TEST_GRADLE Command: /jdk-1.6.0_16/linux-redhat/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/javadoc @/TEST_GRADLE/build/tmp/extractRequirements/javadoc.options
Successfully started process 'command '/jdk-1.6.0_16/linux-redhat/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/javadoc''
javadoc: error - invalid flag: -d

the javadoc.options content is

```
-d '/TEST_GRADLE/build/requirements'
-doclet 'com.xxx.CustomDoclet'
-docletpath '/TEST_GRADLE/gradle_home/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com/customdoclet/1.0/f9a374632048d2e68cc0eb102d47f73db65b786c/customdoclet-1.0.jar'
-doctitle 'TEST_GRADLE API'
-quiet 
-windowtitle 'TEST_GRADLE API'
'.... test.java files'
'.... test.java files'
'.... test.java files'
'.... test.java files'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My doclet was not extending the `Standard` doclet class, which contains some basic options, like '-d'
Extending the StandardDoclet solved the problem.